# Group by count of request body param using Prometheus in springboot application

Tags: java, prometheus, metrics, micrometer

Sample Request

```
{
"ScenarioId":12,
"type":"t1"
}
```

Here type can be t1,t2,t3....etc

Can we take count of type param using  group by in Prometheus?

Kindly help here to understand the Prometheus custom metric

Is it possible to read json request and take a count of request param?